# LinkedList in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm writing a LinkedList class for an assignment and I'm writing my insert method and was wondering if I could get it looked at.

```
private Node first;     // start of the list

private class Node {
    private Item item;
    private Node next;
}

public boolean insert(Item item) {
    // add item to list if it doesn't already exist
    // return true if a new Node is created, otherwise false
    if ( first.next == null && first.item == item) {
        return false;
    }
    Node ptr = first;
    while (ptr.next != null) {
        if (ptr.item == item) {
            return false;
        }
        ptr = ptr.next;
    }
    Node oldFirst = first;
    first = new Node();
    first.item = item;
    first.next = oldFirst;
    return true;
}
```

For the most part I think it's okay, but everytime I try to trace the insert method I end up confusing myself and messing up all the reference changes. Can someone tell me if I'm doing it right? Any other improvements would be appreciated too.

Comment: Have you considered writing a JUnit test case to assert that it works properly?

Comment: @Thilo um...no I haven't. Honestly I don't know what that is...sorry! I'm in an intro to CS course in college right now...

Comment: First thing I have noticed is that this will throw a NPE for the first item inserted.

Comment: @threenplusone can you elaborate on why?

Comment: also, it seems that you are using `==` instead of `equals()` to check if items already exist, maybe that is a problem.

Comment: The 'first' variable is not set prior to the "if ( first.next == null && ..." line. Unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider writing an extra function for checking if the Item is already in the list. This would make the insert function more clear and the whole reference changing would only be there. Also your first test:

```
if ( first.next == null && first.item == item) {
    return false;
}
```

does nothing else then the first iteration of the while loop.

You should definitely initialize first so that you don't throw a NullPointerExcpetion as @threenplusone said or check if:`first == null`. (the first ptr.next in your while-loop throws a NPE if first is null)
Also you should compare your items by equals as @Thilo said.

The rest is correct I think.

Answer (score -1):

Your insert method is not OO - you're using a `while` loop to traverse the list, so this method could be a `static` method (if you also passed in the first node).

A more elegant way would be:

In pseudo-code:

```
insert(item) {
    if (next == null)
        add item to "this" // we are at end of list
    else
        next.insert(item) // hand item to the next node
}
```

Comment: Why is using a loop instead of recursion (which is nice, of course), not OO? The method certainly cannot be static, because it needs access to the `first` field.

Comment: @Bohemian this would add items to the end of the list, right? I'm implementing a stack with this LinkedList, which is why I wanted to add new items to the front...but great answer. A lot less messy. +1

Comment: @Thilo Obviously it can be static by passing in the first node (and the item) to the method. OK, it's still OO in the sense that the muck is contained, but it's an inelegant approach IMHO. Edited my answer to clarify/justify/defend/etc

Comment: FWIW, java.util.LinkedList is also implemented using loops. http://docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html

Comment: The method is not part of the Node-Class but the LinkedList-Class so your version would be less OO since a node has not the responsibility to add an Item to itself or any other node in my opinion.

Comment: @Thilo sure loops are faster and use less stack than what is essentially recursive, however for what is clearly a programming assignment, I know I'd be more impressed with cleaner loop-less code. btw, apparently I skimmed the question and this isn't what he wants anyway :( (still haven't read it thoroughly - maybe a bit later when I have time). Cheers